# MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '('id')

Tags: mysql

i get this error when i try to inport to data base

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '('id')
) TYPE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=6' at line 4

```
 DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `categories`;
 CREATE TABLE `categories` (
 `id` int(5) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `category` varchar(50) NOT NULL default '',
  PRIMARY KEY  ('id')
  ) TYPE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=6 ;
```

Comment: The curious thing is that the error occurs *before* the opening parenthesis defining the `PRIMARY KEY` columns: one would expect it to occur after that parenthesis, upon encountering the string quotation character `'`.  This implies that you have some other problem, in addition to [those cited by @bluefeet, below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16607483).  What are the characters between `PRIMARY KEY` and `('id')` (in your question they are space characters, U+0020, but perhaps your code has some other oddity in reality)?

Answer (score 3):

You are using `'` here

```
PRIMARY KEY  ('id')
```

`id` is in this case a string, not the column name. Use backticks instead.

```
PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
```

Comment: Also note bluefeet's issue with `ENGINE` instead of `TYPE`.

Answer (score 2):

You have two issues with the code, remove the single quotes around the `id` in the primary key declaration. You can use backticks or nothing.

And change the `Type=MyISAM` to:

```
ENGINE=MyISAM
```

From the [MySQL Docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/myisam-storage-engine.html):

> The older term TYPE is supported as a synonym for ENGINE for backward compatibility, but ENGINE is the preferred term and TYPE is deprecated.

So the script will be:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `categories`;
 CREATE TABLE `categories` (
 `id` int(5) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `category` varchar(50) NOT NULL default '',
  PRIMARY KEY  (id)
  ) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=6 ;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9ad20/1)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `categories`;
 CREATE TABLE `categories` (
 `id` int(5) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `category` varchar(50) NOT NULL default '',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
  ) ENGINE=MYISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=6
```

The problems is that `PRIMARY KEY  ('id')` should use backquotes insted of quotes

Comment: @steve Could you try this one now? It will work... it was because ENGINE was not specified.

Answer (score -2):

1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM disc_disc WHERE disc_id=NULL' at line 1 SQL=SELECT disc_id, disc_name, FROM disc_disc WHERE disc_id=NULL

```
    // zjistit jmeno diskuse
$disc_name = "";
$sql = sprintf("SELECT disc_id, disc_name, " .
    "FROM disc_disc " .
    "WHERE disc_id=%s",
quote_smart($disc_id));
$db->setQuery($sql);
$rec = $db->loadObjectList();

if ($db->getErrorNum()) {
    JError::raiseWarning( 500, $db->stderr() );
}
```

Comment: This does not address the question at all and should be deleted.